# Can I connect my android phone to the LAN, via an ethernet cable?

Tags: usb, lan

I want to connect my Galaxy S2 HD LTE SHV-120S Android version 4.0 (rooted) to the internet via a LAN connection. I am sensitive to wifi and network radiation, hence want to make a line connection and keep my phone on airplane mode.
BobjGear mentions some tablets have the required settings, but no phones.
I have an OTG cable, a USB LAN adapter, and a usb cable. I did not find any ethernet drivers on Google Playstore.
Would CyanogenMod or Ubuntu OS have this support?
If it is not possible with this phone, which phones can be configured for it?

Comment: Look for an adapter for the ethernet cable and plug it in your usb port with an `otg cable`

Comment: @SuperThomasLab But will the android device both detect and work the Ethernet connection at all. That's my question. Have you ever read or been through such scenario? Consider sourcing it if you did.

Comment: Yes I have a usb to LAN adapter and an OTG cable. I have made all connections but the phone does not recognise the adapter, Even after connecting to a live ethernet port there is no recognition. Should I change any settings on the phone? Are there any drivers I can install? I found a couple apps on PlayStore but they did not work. I am quite new at Android, so any recommendations would be very welcome. How would I "source" it?

Comment: For the completeness of the thread, here is a list of USB OTG compatible devices: http://plugable.com/products/usb2-otge100

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53443/how-to-use-an-usb-attached-wired-ethernet-adapter-through-usb-otg-on-an-android

Comment: "I am sensitive to wifi and network radiation". No you're not. Nobody is. I'm not trolling, just pointing out that there's no need for you to go to these lengths. Also, your symptoms might be symptoms of something else. Again, not trolling. Concerned! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_hypersensitivity

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)

Comment: @OnePablo this is presumptuous and reminds me radium girls

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a USB-OTG adapter, or equivalently for newer devices with USB-C ports, a USB-C to USB-A adapter, to be able to physically connect a USB Ethernet adapter to your phone.  It'll only work, though, if the phone has a driver for the Ethernet adapter you're using.  That may vary from phone to phone.

[This USB Ethernet adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00484IEJS) has worked for me on several Google-branded Android devices: a Nexus 5, Nexus 5X, and Pixel C tablet.  I've been told by a friend that it also works on the Wii U.  It's an older device (note, doesn't support gigabit) and apparently pretty widely supported.

However, other Android device makers may have removed some drivers from the version of the OS that they ship on their devices, so there's no guarantee that it'll work with every phone.

Answer (score 1):

You need a powered USB hub to make the LAN connection work. Amazon does a cheap powered hub. I have used this set-up for a tablet so it should work with your phone, which has a USB port. You should not need a different driver.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your phone but the Nexus 7 can be configured the way you want, view the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvu33kshlSY).

Alternative Method :

Buy a phone which has a usb internet option in settings (like my htc 816g), and just connect your phone via usb to your computer and share computer's internet with the phone.

In both methods you are safe from radiations of wifi or mobile data.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

You can use something called reverse tethering, it is done by connecting your device with a computer via USB connector.. then you can connect your Ethernet with your computer.. that's how you can use internet in your computer as well as your Android device..