# Will a OTG + USB ethernet cord work for Internet access?

Tags: internet, usb-on-the-go

Will a OTG adapter (the one with a micro-b male on one end and USB 'standard' female port on the other end) connected to a Ethernet to usb  ('standard' USB male one end, female/male Ethernet end on the other) work to connect an Android device to a network, providing of course proper sofware support on the devices side? My guess is yes, but I though maybe their is something special about Micro-b to ethernet adpaters

Example of OTG adapter: https://www.amazon.ca/Micro-USB-OTG-Adapter-Cable/dp/B00D8YZ2SA

Example of Ethernet to USB: https://www.amazon.ca/Cisco-USB300M-Linksys-Ethernet-Adapter/dp/B001NLV4TQ

Comment: See: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53443/how-to-use-an-usb-attached-wired-ethernet-adapter-through-usb-otg-on-an-android TL;DR: It depends on the phone.

Comment: "providing of course proper sofware support on the devices side" - this is where the problem is at, as the OS doesn't include drivers for every possible adapter chipset out there.

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)